# How to refer to function argument which is a builtin function

Tags: r

What I wanted to do was avoid writing a wrapper function around `array` to be able to assign `dimnames` based on the dimensions of the array I'm creating.  (See, for example, the rules for setting the dimnames for an array to be fed to `e1071:interpolate` ).

This function works:

```
# for , say, x<-array(1:24,dim=c(2,3,4))
foofunc <- function(x,  mid=sapply(1:length(dim(eval(substitute(x))) ), function(j) 1:(dim(eval(substitute(x) ) )[j]) ) ) {
dimnames(x)<-mid
return(x)
    }
```

But the named argument for `apply` is `dim` , so if I try

```
 bar<-array(1:24,dim=c(2,3,4), dimnames=sapply (1:length(eval(substitute(dim))),function(j) 1:(eval(substitute(dim))[j]) ))
```

The error is, not surprisingly:

```
Error in eval(substitute(dim))[j] : 
  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

I know I can easily assign `dimnames` either via a wrapper function or a second line of code, but wondered if there's any way around this kerfluffle of a named argument which is also a builtin function.

Edit: to clarify, my technique is similar to many functions which retrieve the external variable name, e.g.  `function(x,xname=deparse(substitute(x)))`, which assigns to `xname` the actual name of the object fed to the function.   The problem here is that the named argument in `array` is `dim` , which conflicts with the builtin function `dim` .

Comment: You can't access the values of parameter in a function signature via their names from the calling environment. (At least, not normally). For example the latter doesn't work here `ff<-function(a=4, b=a+2) print(a+b); ff(1); ff(1, a+5);`. At least I think that's your problem. I must admit I find the example a bit confusing. You didn't provide the desired output from this function.

Comment: @MrFlick  The output of my working `foofunc` is the input array with `dimnames` assigned to all three dimensions, the names running from "1" to the length of said dimension. I'll edit to explain more.

Comment: I wonder if it would help to specify the environment when calling `substitute(dim, env=)`?

Comment: you could get it all in one expression using `\`dimnames<-\`(expr,mid)`

Comment: @NealFultz could you explain a bit more about that?  thanks.

Comment: I just now saw your edit. Those types of otpions work only as default values for parameters to a function. Not that you cannot pass the same thing to the function and get the same behavior. There is a default separation between the calling environment and the definition environment. `foo <- function(x,xname=deparse(substitute(x))) {xname}; n<-"hello"; foo(n); foo(n, xname=deparse(substitute(x)))`